# How to send a POST request using HTTPie?

Tags: http, post, silex, httpie

I have a basic silex application, and I try to test it using [HTTPie](https://github.com/jkbrzt/httpie). Yet when posting using:

```
http POST http://localhost:1337 data="hello world"
```

The `data`, that I get from the Request object via:

```
$data = $request->request->get('data');
```

will always be empty. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It was an httpie usage problem as the `form` flag was necessary, as silex requires the parameters to be form-encoded, yet the default of HTTPie is to pass a JSON object.

```
$ http --form POST http://localhost:1337 data="hello world"

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Wed, 14 Oct 2015 15:04:09 GMT
Host: localhost:1337
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.13

{
    "message": "hello world"
}
```

Comment: One can also accept json payload in silex: https://silex.symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/json_request_body.html

Comment: https://silex.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cookbook/json_request_body.html

Answer (score 6):

Just to clarify what kOpernikus said, when you are making a POST request using httpie, use the following syntax:

```
   http --form post :3000/register username="gilbert" password="stackoverflow!"
```

Alternatively, since forms are for `post` requests you can leave out `post` and also abbreviate `--form` to `-f` like so:

```
   http -f :3000/register username=gilbert password=stackoverflow!
```

EDIT (thanks to Aerials)

To pass csrf token as header in the post request do:

```
http --form POST http://localhost:8000/login/ username=user password=pass X-CSRFToken:assQ$%auxASDLSIAJSd
```

Comment: What if you have to pass a `csrf token` in the POST request along with username and password?

Comment: Well it depends. If the csrf token is to be passed in the form and not the headers you can use: http -f :3000/profile username='harantula' password='itmo' csrftoken='akskadlsjd123$11d'

Comment: To pass `csrf token` as header in the post request do: `http --form POST http://localhost:8000/login/ username=user password=pass X-CSRFToken:assQ$%auxASDLSIAJSd`