# php jquery dynamic dropdown

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am having problem sending/reading ajax variable.

Ajax code is as below:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/wp-content/themes/canvas-child/get-clients-dropdown.php?it=1",
    success: function(data) {
        $("#ClientID").html(data);
    }
});
```

I have tried to read it in another php file like this:

```
$InvoiceType = $_REQUEST['it'];
//$InvoiceType = $_POST['it'];
//$InvoiceType = $_GET['it'];
```

But none of above works. The variable $InvoiceType always stays empty.

What is the problem?

Comment: So `print_r` `$_REQUEST` in this another php file. And also print `$_GET`

Comment: are u echo $InvoiceType; in php file , if not than it will not return 1

Comment: did u checked as @u_mulder said??? print_r($_REQUEST)... r u not getting values in php or in ajax response?

Comment: Check if you send the data as json or if it's form-encoded.

Comment: This reminds me of a similar yet problem I had: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33128993/how-to-send-a-post-request-using-httpie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to use POST method like this : 

`$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: ""/wp-content/themes/canvas-child/get-clients-dropdown.php",
    data: { it: 1, param2: "value2" }
})`

You can get your value in `$_POST['it']`

Comment: I have tried post method before, but wasn't working.

Comment: The method POST is not the only important line. 'data' line is necessary to send data to $_POST

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      data: {it: "1"}, 
      url: "/wp-content/themes/canvas-child/get-clients-dropdown.php?it=1",
      success: function(data) {
         $("#ClientID").html(data);
      }
});
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

Please try it with full url of file with `get_template_directory_uri()`.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/get-clients-dropdown.php',
    data: {it: 1},
    success: function(data) {
            $("#ClientID").html(data);
          }
     });
```

Comment: File is executed, so this is not a problem. Like said, everything Works for me, exept I have problem transfering variable value.

Comment: @gdolenc Did you try it with send data from "data: {it: 1}," ?

Comment: @gdolenc Can you please check it with print_r($_REQUEST) on that file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use it like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/wp-content/themes/canvas-child/get-clients-dropdown.php?it=1",
    success: function(data) {
        $("#ClientID").html(data);
    }
});
```

Then in PHP File use this:

```
$InvoiceType = $_POST['it'];
```

Comment: Are you using it in "get-clients-dropdown.php" file?

Comment: This is the beginning of my get-clients-dropdown.php file: 

    <?php

    $InvoiceType = $_POST['it'];
    echo 'InvoiceType: ' . $InvoiceType . '<br>';

Comment: @gdolenc Welcome. Appriciated for your up vote. Thanks