# How to send POST to MongoDB Atlas using HTTPie?

Tags: http, curl, post, http-headers, httpie

I'm attempting to test my REST API by making a POST request to a MongoDB cloud Atlas DB server. I know Postman is available, but I wanted to use something different like Httpie. I already checked this question but I'm still stuck. 
[How to send a POST request using HTTPie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33128993/how-to-send-a-post-request-using-httpie)

I'm trying to get `text='john smith'`

when I use

```
`http -f POST :5000/api/posts text='john smith'`
```

I get this response.

```
`HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 19 Feb 2019 20:33:36 GMT
X-Powered-By: Express`
```

But when I use...

`http -f GET :5000/api/posts`

I get back ...

```
`[
   {
        "_id": "5c6c6820c2f6eb15ea9e8e08",
        "createdAt": "2019-02-19T20:33:36.468Z",
        "text": null
    }
]`
```

This is my Nodejs API for the post

```
router.post('/', async(req, res) => {
    const posts = await loadPostCollection();
    await posts.insertOne({
        text: req.body.text,
        createdAt: new Date()
    });
    res.status(201).send();
});
```